# как убрать стандартный просмотр фото, что бы все фото открывались определенным плагином wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Запилил через html дивы аккордеон, в них перестали открываться фото лайтбоксом, сразу бросает на страницу фото. Подскажите как можно решить проблему. Поставил плагин лайтбокса, теперь в дивах все норм открывает, но на отдельных страницах не в диве открывает сразу два лайтбокса стандартный и установленный!

Comment: или как сделать что бы стандартным открывались те что перестали открываться ??

Comment: "Запилил через html дивы аккордеон": приводите код. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать ...  минимальный код прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так получилось

```
<div class="column mcb-column one column_image_gallery ">
                <style type="text/css">
                    #sc_gallery-1 {
                        margin: auto;
                    }
                    #sc_gallery-1 .gallery-item {
                        float: left;
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 33.33%;
                    }
                    #sc_gallery-1 img {
                        border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                    }
                    #sc_gallery-1 .gallery-caption {
                        margin-left: 0;
                    }
                    /* see sc_gallery() in functions/theme-shortcodes.php */
                </style>
            <div id="sc_gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-168 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-medium file fancy"><dl class="gallery-item">
                    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                        <div class="image_frame scale-with-grid"><div class="image_wrapper"><a href="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827.jpg" rel="lightbox[sc_gallery-1]" data-type="gallery"><div class="mask"></div><img width="300" height="199" src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-300x199.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" srcset="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-300x199.jpg 300w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-768x510.jpg 768w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-1024x680.jpg 1024w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-220x146.jpg 220w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-50x33.jpg 50w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3827-113x75.jpg 113w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></div></div>
                    </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
                    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                        <div class="image_frame scale-with-grid"><div class="image_wrapper"><a href="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824.jpg" rel="lightbox[sc_gallery-1]" data-type="gallery"><div class="mask"></div><img width="300" height="199" src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-300x199.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" srcset="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-300x199.jpg 300w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-768x510.jpg 768w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-1024x680.jpg 1024w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-220x146.jpg 220w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-50x33.jpg 50w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3824-113x75.jpg 113w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></div></div>
                    </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
                    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                        <div class="image_frame scale-with-grid"><div class="image_wrapper"><a href="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819.jpg" rel="lightbox[sc_gallery-1]" data-type="gallery"><div class="mask"></div><img width="300" height="199" src="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-300x199.jpg" class="attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" srcset="http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-300x199.jpg 300w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-768x510.jpg 768w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-1024x680.jpg 1024w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-220x146.jpg 220w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-50x33.jpg 50w, http://bobtail-dog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/DSC_3819-113x75.jpg 113w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" style="height: auto; width: 100%;"></a></div></div>
                    </dt></dl>
                </div>
</div>
```